# TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I get a TypeError when I use the following code in my Django Template:

```
{% for signature in petition.get_signatures %}
     {% include 'petition/signature.html' with petition=petition %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here are my models and classes:

```
class Petition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 90, default="Enter petition title here")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='static/petition-photos/%Y/%m/%d')
    video = models.CharField(max_length=600, default="Enter an external video link")
    petition = models.TextField(null=False, default="Type your petition here")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.like_set.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_signatures(self):
        return self.signature_set.all

class Signature(models.Model):
    petition= models.ForeignKey(Petition)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.petition
```

I get the following error message when I load my template view page with the 'for' condition. The error message I get is `'method' object is not iterable`. What might I be doing wrong? Any solutions? I'm kind of a noob so if you could explain the solution too, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call* the `.all()` method:

```
def get_signatures(self):
    return self.signature_set.all()
```

You returned the method object itself, rather than the result it produces when called, and the `{% for signature in ..` loop tries to iterate over that method object, and can't.